# ¿Cómo eliminar registros de SQL Server cuando un campo tiene un espacio al inicio?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un problema en mis registros de SQL Server: se insertaron campos con un espacio vacío al inicio.

Por ejemplo, en el campo `nombre` tiene `" Alberto"`, cuando debería ser `"Alberto"`.

Al hacer una consulta, debo usar

```
LIKE '%Alberto%'
```

el cual me podría regresar más de un resultado como `J. Alberto` o `Luis Alberto`, y no quiero eso. Quiero borrar esos registros, pero no sé cuál sería la consulta que me borre sólo los que tengan espacio al inicio.

Comment: Es necesario eliminar los registros? o actualizando la información para que te corrija el problema te serviría?

Comment: **LTRIM**  podría ser de utilidad para estos casos.

Comment: @Weimar si es necesario eliminarlos, ya que sin conocer de este problema se actualizó todos los registros obteniendolos de la misma base de datos, quitandoles espacios e insertandolos nuevamente, el caso es que si se tenia un registro con espacio al inicio, ahora se tiene dos registros del mismo, uno con espacio y el otro sin el espacio inicial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM tabla WHERE nombre like ' %';
```

acá borramos todo los datos que empiezan con el carácter espacio.

asegúrate de que estés borrando lo que deseas con un SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE nombre like ' %';
```

saludos

Answer (score 5):

Esta consulta te podría valer para eliminarlos:

```
DELETE FROM tabla WHERE nombre != LTRIM(nombre)
```

También podrías eliminar esos espacios actualizando esos campos con un `update`:

```
UPDATE tabla SET nombre = LTRIM(nombre);
```

Answer (score -1):

Hay una funcion que te puede ayudar al momento de realizar tu consulta.

```
SELECT TRIM('   Sample   ');
Resultado.
'Sample'
```

Lo que realiza es traer todos los registros de la columna que requieras y eliminar espacios tanto del inicio como del final.

Puedes echar un vistazo.
http://developerji.com/Post/Como-eliminar-los-espacios-en-blanco-en-SQL/1036

Desconozco si esta funcion puede utilizarse en el where de la consulta.

Comment: Sí, se puede usar, como se observa en la respuesta ya publicada

Answer (score -1):

Para evitar espacios de ambos lados te conviene hacer:

```
Ltrim(Rtrim('   Sample   '))
```